# Exclude XSLT's (1.0) line returns and extra whitespace in text output

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm guilty of wanting my XSLT to look pretty and hence readable. So I indent and include line breaks as such. But the transform takes these literally (which I understand why), but I don't know if there is an option to exclude these. I've searched extensively. I know a couple of years ago I found a solution, but I don't recall what it was.

This transformation is used to generate a single line Email Subject and hence I don't want the extra white space and line returns.

How can I have my readable XSLT with my desired, single line text output?

Example to play with: [xsltransform.net](http://xsltransform.net/gWEaStX/1)

**XML Input**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <OrderHeaderId>123456</OrderHeaderId>
    <ProjectName>Project</ProjectName>
    <RequiresApproval>true</RequiresApproval>
</response>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:template match="/response">New Job: <xsl:value-of select="OrderHeaderId"/>: 
        <xsl:if test="RequiresApproval='true'">
            Requires Approval!              
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="ProjectName"/> - Acknowledgement from <xsl:value-of select="SellingCompanyName"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
New Job: 123456: 
        
            Requires Approval!              
        Project - Acknowledgement from Acme
```

** Desired Output**

```
New Job: 123456: Requires Approval! Project - Acknowledgement from Acme
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your stylesheet indented, then use `xsl:text` instructions to output text explicitly:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:template match="/response">
    <xsl:text>New Job: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="OrderHeaderId"/>
    <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:if test="RequiresApproval='true'">
        <xsl:text>Requires Approval! </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="ProjectName"/>
    <xsl:text>- Acknowledgement from </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="SellingCompanyName"/>
</xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Explanation, which may aid in remembering the technique: Explicit `xsl:text` statements help here because they partition the whitespace into *insignificant* whitespace between XSLT elements (used for source indentation) and *significant* whitespace within `xsl:text` statements (used to control output document spacing).

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement to the accepted answer:
[Allouche's method](https://web.archive.org/web/20180305021934/http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/muench.html#d9944e225) - using an empty XSLT element - helps control whitespace, e.g.

```xsl
<xsl:text/>New Job: <xsl:value-of select="OrderHeaderId"/>: <xsl:text/>
```